# Get duplicate State Names for countries

Tags: sql-server

I have a state table which has states assigned to different countries. There are cases where different countries have same state names. How can I get that. I am trying the following query. Am I right.?

```
SELECT  Name , COUNT(*) count 
FROM 
[DB].[dbo].[State]
GROUP BY
 Name
Having
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Above query gives correct result. But following query is that I am trying to fetch Country Names also. This is not working

```
SELECT  st.Name , COUNT(*) count,co.Name 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] st
INNER join [DB].[dbo].Country co on st.CountryID  = co.ID
GROUP BY
st.Name,
co.Name
Having
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Try my Updated Answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct so I don't understand what is the question?

If you want it with the countries name and all the other information you can use `EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] s
             WHERE t.state = s.state and t.country <> s.country)
```

**EDIT:** Try this

```
SELECT  st.Name ,co.Name 
FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] st
INNER join [DB].[dbo].Country co on st.CountryID  = co.ID
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] st2
             WHERE st.name = st2.name
             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: @user2998990 See mine.

Comment: Quick question. Can't we use group by and get the same result.?

Comment: No problem . Yes, instead of `EXISTS()` make another join to `(SELECT ... FROM STATE.. GROUP BY.. HAVING COUNT > 1)` . Either way you have to select from state twice.

Comment: I am new to sql. Can you please help me.?

Comment: Why don't you just use this query?

Answer (score 0):

Hope your Query is correct.,

```
SELECT  st.Name,co.Name,COUNT(st.CountryID) [count]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[State] st
LEFT join [DB].[dbo].Country co on st.CountryID  = co.ID
GROUP BY
st.Name,co.Name
Having
COUNT(st.CountryID) > 1
```

Comment: Unless he has null values, which is not very logical, this query will have the exact same results as his.

Comment: Not working. I am not getting any row. Where as I was getting rows when I don't have country in picture.